# Intercepting a system call

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel

I have been trying to hook the system calls at the kernel level.I got the basic idea from this question.The system call I was trying to intercept was the `fork()`. So I found out the address of the `sys_call_table` from `System.map` and it turned out to be 0xc12c9e90.Now I wrote the module as below.

```
#include<linux/kernel.h>
#include<linux/module.h>
#include<linux/unistd.h>
#include<linux/semaphore.h>
#include<asm/cacheflush.h>
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
void **sys_call_table;
unsigned long addr;
asmlinkage int (*original_call)(struct pt_regs);
asmlinkage int our_call(struct pt_regs regs)
{
        printk("Intercepted sys_fork");
        return original_call(regs);
}
static int __init p_entry(void)
{
       struct page *pg;
       printk(KERN_ALERT "Module Intercept inserted");
       sys_call_table=(void *)0xc12c9e90;
       pg=virt_to_page(sys_call_table);
       addr=(unsigned long)page_address(pg);
       set_memory_rw(addr,1);
       original_call=sys_call_table[__NR_fork];
       sys_call_table[__NR_fork]=our_call;
       set_memory_ro(addr,1);
       return 0;
}
static void __exit p_exit(void)
{
       sys_call_table[__NR_fork]=original_call;
       set_memory_ro(addr,1);
       printk(KERN_ALERT "Module Intercept removed");
}
module_init(p_entry);
module_exit(p_exit);
```

I compiled the module and tried to insert it to the kernel.Unfortunately the dmesg output gave me a message as follows **BUG:unable to handle kernel paging request at c12c9e98** and here is the ellaborate dmesg out put

[image]
[image]

As an experiment to find out the problem, I simply commented out the line

```
sys_call_table[__NR_fork]=our_call;
```

After that I repeated the compilation and followed by insertion.And it didn't show up any errors. So I concluded that ,the above specified line which assigns the new function in to sys_call_table is the problem. But I don't know what could be causing it and how to solve it.Can any one help me out to solve it?

Comment: @alexmurray did you see the line set_memory_rw(addr,1)?

Comment: If you compile the module with debug symbols, and check out which line is at p_entry+0x3a in gdb, what do you get?